# Mouse and keyboard are not responseive after Windows 8.1 Upgrade

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-8.1, windows-8.1-upgrade

I recently upgraded my Windows 8 installation to 8.1. Now when I boot my laptop, I get to the screen before the login screen (the one where you must click the touchpad or press a key to progress to the actual login screen). However nothing happens when I click the touchpad or type on the keyboard.

I have booted to a Ubuntu USB and I can see the Windows filesystem, but when I try to view it I get an error saying "The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option."

Can anyone help me out?